# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation Identifier name too long when running laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application I have following migration file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSchedulesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('schedules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id');
            $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('company_id');
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('added_by');
            $table->foreign('added_by')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('schedule_name');
            $table->integer('schedule_type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('schedule_type_id')->references('id')->on('schedule_types');
            $table->date('schedule_start_date')->nullable();
            $table->date('schedule_end_date')->nullable();
            $table->date('schedule_actual_end_date')->nullable();
            $table->time('schedule_travel_time')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('rotation_scheme_id');
            $table->foreign('rotation_scheme_id')->references('id')->on('schedule_rotational');
            $table->date('rotational_schedule_period_from')->nullable();
            $table->date('rotational_schedule_period_to')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->index([
                'department_id', 'user_id', 'schedule_type_id', 'company_id', 'added_by','schedule_start_date',
                'schedule_end_date', 'rotation_scheme_id', 'rotational_schedule_period_from', 'rotational_schedule_period_to',
                'rotation_shift_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('schedules');
    }
}
```

but when I try to run this i'm getting following error,

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
> 1059 Identifier name
> 'schedules_department_id_user_id_schedule_type_id_company_id_added_by_schedule_start_date_schedule...' is too long")

Comment: Your index name is too long, I think the default is max 64 characters. See this link for the docs on indexing. The fourth part is about naming indexes. [Click me!](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#creating-indexes)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has generated the index name.
But the index name is too long. MySQL has a limit of 64 characters per index name.

But you can set your own index name. It's the second parameter of the "foreign" method.

```
 $table->foreign($fieldName, $indexName);
```

Example:

```
$table->foreign('user_id', 'fk_user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Comment: Why do you think this error has anything to do with foreign keys?

Answer (score -1):

Please note that you had to first kind of declare the field. It must be declared as unsignedBigInteger; because primary keys in laravelare declared as unsigned so forign key must also be unsigned.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('date_of_handing_over_cpis_id');
```

then declare that field as forign key.

```
        $table->foreign('date_of_handing_over_cpis_id', 'fk_date_of_handing_over_cpis_id')
        ->references('id')->on('date_of_handing_over_cpis')
        ->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
```

Comment: I don't know why my answer is downgraded. Because I executed and verified that it works. Please when you downgrade have the decency to say why you downgrade. Maybe the downgrader didn't like my use of the word declaring the column first but we must specify the field type before saying what base table it is referencing. I challenge the downgrader to prove me wrong. I only share when first I executed the code myself and it works and solves the problem.